# How to do explicit Facebook logout?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

Using newest Facebook iOS sdk, and I need to do explicit Facebook logout including wiping user credentials, so the next time user presses my login button he will be forced to enter his Facebook login & pass. The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649799/597292) didn't worked for me when running on simulation. SSO opens safari but the cookie storage is empty.

Comment: Did you also wipe out FBAccessTokenKey and FBExpirationDateKey keys from NSUserDefaults as stated in Facebook iOS SDK example? I just did implement Facebook into another app I'm working on and I have no problems in Simulator, on device, everything works like a charm. It's enough to call `logout` and I'm wiping out these keys in `fbDidLogout`.

Comment: I'm making [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] method call in my logout. And I'm not storing FBAccessTokenKey and FBExpirationDateKey in NSUserDefaults. What Facebook example are you referencing?

Comment: Did you read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ ? It's step by step how to integrate Facebook iOS SDK. And if you follow all steps, it should work. It does work for me in many apps and I'm not fiddling with FBSession.activeSession, ...

Comment: I'v started by using guidelines defined [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project) and used Scrumptious as example. In its source code Facebook is added as compiled library and there's no such FBConnect file and Facebook class in header files. However, those classes exist in uncompiled source. Maybe compiled one is  stripped? I took compiled framework from Facebook SDK install directory. Personally, I would prefer using compiled library...

Comment: It appears Facebook and FBConnect are deprecated. If you would install Facebook iOS 3 and go to framework/Versions/current you will find "Deprecated header" folder containing Facebook and FBConnect headers. Also, the info in your link is probably also outdated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```